# Is there any functions to automatically add text to selected blank cell? (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I want to write a Google Sheet script to add same text to selected blank cells. For example, [here is the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhvlx.png). I select A1:A15 and by a script, I can add "3.7 miss" or other texts to these selected blank cells.

I have a script that can add date to all selected cells but I don't know how to edit it.

```
 function addDate() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  let promptVal = ui.prompt("add date: ").getResponseText()
  let oldValues = range.getValues()
  let newValues = oldValues.map(pItem => {
    if (!pItem[0].toString().startsWith(promptVal)) {
      return [promptVal + pItem[0]]
    }
    return pItem
  })
  
  range.setValues(newValues);
}
```

Comment: thank u so much! It works so well! I have another question: I need to add different texts every day. Is there other way that i can type simple before using this script? Thank u so much!

Comment: If you have a question for the answer author below, comment under their answer, not under the question. The answer author won't be automatically notified of comments on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following expected result,

> Is there any functions to automatically add text to selected blank cell? (Google Sheet)
>
> I want to write a Google Sheet script to add same text to selected blank cells. For example, Here is the sheet I select A1:A15 and by a script, I can add "3.7 miss" or other texts to these selected blank cells.

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you select cells on the Spreadsheet, you want to automatically put a value of `3.7 miss` to the empty cells.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And please set a value to `const text = "3.7 miss";` you want to put to the empty cells.

When you use this script, please select cells. By this, `3.7 miss` is put into the empty cells of the selected cells.

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const text = "3.7 miss"; // Please set a text you want to put to the empty cells.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const rangeList = range.getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (!c) {
        ar.push(sheet.getRange(range.rowStart + i, range.columnStart + j).getA1Notation());
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(text);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following situation is obtained. In this sample situation, a text of `sample` is put into the empty cells of selected cells.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this sample, from `automatically add text` of `Is there any functions to automatically add text to selected blank cell? (Google Sheet)`, I used `onSelectionChange`. This is a function by executing with a trigger. For example, when a cell is selected, this function is automatically run.
- For example, if you want to manually run with the script editor, I think that the following script might be able to be used. In this case, after you select cells, when you run this script, `text` is put into the empty cells.

  ```js
  function sample() {
    const text = "3.7 miss"; // Please set a text you want to put to the empty cells.

    const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const rangeList = range.getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (!c) {
          ar.push(sheet.getRange(range.getRow() + i, range.getColumn() + j).getA1Notation());
        }
      });
      return ar;
    }, []);
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(text);
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#getrangelista1notations)